# Reload browser (not server) on file change Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the **[node-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-watch)** module and would like to reload just the browser (not the whole server) when a file is changed.

I have the following set up:

```
var watch= require('node-watch');

watch('build/public/js', { recursive: true }, function(filename) {

    console.log(filename, 'was changed');

    // RELOAD THE BROWSER

});
```

I have nodemon but this reloads the server. I would like to just reload the browser while the server is running when node-watch has detected a change.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `livereload`? (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-livereload). It will allow you to connect to a separate server that can trigger a reload if the script is included in your page.

Comment: You'd have to use a library like socket.io to send a respective command to the browser, then use client-side JavaScript to call `document.reload()`